# Why does using list(dict_keys()) here, return an empty list?

Tags: python, dictionary, class, python-3.10

I am trying to make a Class to represent a Library with a nested class to represent the individual books.

```
class Library:
    class Book:
        book_data = {}
        def __init__(self, title, year, isbn, author):
            self.title = title
            self.year = year
            self.isbn = isbn
            self.author = author
            Library.Book.book_data[title]={'Date Published':year,'ISBN':isbn,'Auhthor':author}
    
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username
        self.borrowed_books = []

    def checkout_book(self, book_name):
        pass

    def return_book(self, book_name):
        pass

    available_books = Book.book_data.keys()
```

When I print out Library.available_books I get the expected result:
`dict_keys(['Book1','Book2'])`

However when I try to convert dict_keys to list by doing so:
`available_books = list(Book.book_data.keys())`

Printing Library.available_books gives me an empty list. Is there a reason why python is converting the keys into an empty list?

Comment: Did you try the conversion at the same place in the code where currently the `available_books = Book.book_data.keys()` is?

Comment: *When* did you do `available_books = list(Book.book_data.keys())`?  That captures the set of keys at that exact moment in time, the list isn't going to magically change later when you add new books.

Comment: With the way the code is currently structured, `Library.available_books` is only evaluated once when constructing the `Library` class.  You may wish to create a function or turn that into a property.

Comment: I don't see any code that attempts to create either any books or any libraries. Please read [ask] and [mre]. Make sure that someone can **copy and paste** the code in the question **without adding or changing anything** and see the **exact problem, directly**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`available_books = Book.book_data.keys()` is run only once, when the dict is empty. Its value will **not** change each time it is accessed. `dict.keys()` returns a view of the keys, so you can see modifications after changing the underlying `dict`, but converting to a `list` only captures the keys (of which there are none) at the moment `available_books` is initialized.